# JWT mismatch error while authenticating at APIGateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud

Its possible I am making holy grail of mistake here, been following guide to implement JWT authentication on spring-cloud. Library (jjwt) used in guide has has gone through some changes from the time when guide was published.
Adding token header to response received from successful authentication.
I was trying to implement as per latest documentation, I am really clueless what is going wrong.

API Gateway/ AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java

```
private boolean isJwtValid(String jwt) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String subject = null;
        String tokenSecret = env.getProperty("token.secret");
        SecretKey signingKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(tokenSecret.getBytes());

        JwtParser parser = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(signingKey).build();
        
        try {
            Jwt<Header, Claims> parsedToken = (Jwt<Header, Claims>) parser.parseUnsecuredClaims(jwt);
            subject = parsedToken.getPayload().getSubject();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("ERRRRRRRRROR");
        }
        
        if(subject !=null && !subject.isEmpty()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

UserApplication / AuthenticationFilter.java

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUserDetailsByEmail(userName);
        String tokenSecret = environment.getProperty("token.secret");
        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(tokenSecret.getBytes());
        SecretKey secretKey = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secretKeyBytes);
        
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String token = Jwts.builder().subject(userDto.getUserId()).expiration(
                Date.from(now.plusMillis(Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("token.expiration_time")))))
        .issuedAt(Date.from(now))
        .signWith(secretKey)
        .compact();
        
        res.addHeader("token", token);
        res.addHeader("userId", userDto.getUserId());
    }
```

Exception Message: io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

Comment: Perhaps share the exception/error you are getting. It will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

Comment: are you sure your signing key is the correct key required for verifying the signature? The key is signed with a private key and you should be using the corresponding public key to verify the signature.

Comment: using same key on both sides.

Comment: In the `ApplicationFilter` you are getting the secret from an ENV, getting the bytes and then getting the Base64 of those. You do not get the Base64 in the `AuthroizationHeaderFilter`. I think you need to remove the Base64 bit.

Comment: thanks I see progress, although getting different error now.
io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: Unexpected Claims JWS.